# Please help me find the error in my solution of the work done by gravity in a falling chain problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, power

The problem is as follows:
A uniform chain of length $l$ and mass $m$ overhangs a smooth table with one third of the chain hanging off the table. Find the work done by gravity when it completely falls of the table.

The first way to solve this problem is pretty simple, by calculating the loss in potential energy. I wanted to try a different approach so I did this:

Where $F$ is force on chain

$$F= v(dm/dt)+m(dv/dt)$$

Now here $dv/dt=g$

And let $dm/dx=k$ (where $x$ is length of chain)
Therefore $F = kv^2 + kgx$

Now
$$v^2=u^2+2gx$$

$u=0$ (given)
Therefore $v^2=2gx$

Therefore $F=2kgx+kgx$

$F=3kgx$

Therefore work done is
$$\int F \,dx\int3kgx\,dx=3kgx^2/2$$

Now putting limits from $l/3$ to $l$

We get

$4kgl^2/3$

The denominator should be $9$ not $3$, and i don't see where I've gone wrong. Please help.

Comment: You took $\frac{dv}{dt}$ = g which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks but then what is dv/dt? Isnt it the acceleration due to gravity, which remains constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume that $\dfrac {dv}{dt}=g$ in this case.

We can only say $\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ is $g$ if we have $\Sigma F=m\dfrac{dv}{dt}\implies m\dfrac{dv}{dt}=mg\implies\dfrac{dv}{dt}=g$. However, you have that $$\Sigma F=m\dfrac{dv}{dt}+v\dfrac{dm}{dt}=mg$$ so you can't make this assumption.